# Dripping toilet with vertical plunger

Tags: leak, toilet

My toilet drips and I have no idea what to do about it.

It's a vertical style plunger with a button on top (not a handle) with 2 flushes. I can stop it constantly filling by using a pen to raise the float, which stops the water filling. However, the water continues to drain out until empty.

What do I need to check /test to find the source of the problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 2 problems:

1. "constantly filling"- the **fill valve** (often referred to as the *ballcock valve*) needs repair. Often this is simple, get as much information on the valve make and model (often there are maker's marks on the valve itself) and buy a rebuild kit at a good local plumbing shop.
2. "water continues to drain out"- the **flush valve** (this is whatever plunger/ball/flapper type sealing apparatus that is raised/lifted/moved when you press the flush button/lever) needs repair or replacement, same advice for that as in prior step.

Note- if you were to include pictures of the internal tank components we might be able to give more information.